# updateOrCreate isn't filling all the fields in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have a code:-

```
$tokenUpdated = AppToken::updateOrCreate(
                        array(
                        'user_id' => $user_id, 'token' => $token),
                        array('expiry'=>$expiryTime,
                            'created_date'=>$created_at,
                            'modified_date'=>$created_at)
                    );
```

Though new rows are being inserted, the `expiry`, `created_date` fields values aren't getting saved. They records show NULL value which are default values.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if `expiry` and `created_date` are returning values, if so then you could use the updateOrCreate function like this:

```
$tokenUpdated = AppToken::updateOrCreate(
                 ['user_id' => $user_id, 'token' => $token]
                 ['expiry'=>$expiryTime,
                   'created_date'=>$created_at,
                   'modified_date'=>$created_at
                 ]
                );
```

check laravel eloquent documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent